# Как передать метод класса в addEventListener в конструкторе JS 2015?

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6, listener

Всем привет!
Хочу назначить слушателей при создании объекта:

```
class ListenerClass{
    constructor(){
        document.addEvetListener('mousedown', function(event){
            this.consoleCoordinate(event);
        })
    }
    consoleCoordinate(event){
        console.log('x:' + event.clientX);
    }

}
```

На выходу при каждом клике получаю ошибку, что consoleCoordinate is not a function. Само собой, потому что `this` в `this.consoleCoordinate` относиться к контексту `addEventListener`.
Это понятно...
Вопрос - а как передать теперь этот метод в `addEventListener` в конструкторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    document.addEvetListener('mousedown', (function(event){
        this.consoleCoordinate(event);
    }).bind(this))
```

или

```
    document.addEvetListener('mousedown', event => {
        this.consoleCoordinate(event);
    })
```

Comment: Думаю второй вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. лексически привязан к классу

Comment: Просто супер! Спасибо большое!!!!!!

Comment: Второй вариант до конца не понимаю. Мне кажется первый правильнее - тут используется метод, который как раз нужен для того, чтобы явным образом привязать контекст класса к обработчику: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn569317(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Эх... Ну вот. Нашёл повод поспать, а теперь снова придётся учиться всю ночь...

Comment: @O.O оба - правильные. Стрелочные функции (в них `this` - тот же, что в коде, в котором они определены) - появились в ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Igor Всё понял, спасибо. Удобно, кстати